# Python commands to check hardware capabilities

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, hardware

I use MATLAB and for the purposes of multiprocessing applications I know there are several commands in MATLAB that allow you to see the hardware capabilities of the machine you are operation on, Such as getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS') which returns the number of processors and others which can return the max number of computational threads.

Is there anything like this available in Python. The reason I ask is because I have a python program that has a component which is executed in parallel and when the program has been deployed on other machines of lesser computation power it has tended to crash or freeze the weaker machines.

So I am looking for a method to check the capabilities of the machine programmatically and then scale down (or up) the number of workers (parallel operations) in order to fit the capabilities of that machine.

Comment: on linux, you can simply read relevant files, such as `/proc/stat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In unix, relevant file in `/proc` and `/dev` have info about system. you can read such files programmatically

```
>>> with open("/proc/cpuinfo") as file:
        data = file.read().split("\n")
        cores = data[12].split()[2]
        print(cores)
```